# General usage Thunderbolt3 ubunutu 19.10

Tags: uefi, secure-boot, thunderbolt

I do have a Razer Blade Stealth, Razer Core2v, the Core2v conects thru Thunderbolt3 do have a PCIe eGPU, and USB3 ports and also a Gigaethernet NIC

the eGPU works if I turn off Thunderbold Security from user=>none, but USB3 ports doesn't work

- Secure Boot = yes
- Thunderbolt3 Security = user
- UEFI = yes
- Ubuntu = 19.10
- kernel = 5.3.0-18-generic
- KDE Plasma
- dual-boot windows 10

in advance not an english native,any help on how to redact better is also welcome

> sudo ./boltd -r
>
> 7:16:53 bolt 0.8 starting up.
>
> 17:16:53 store: located at: /var/lib/boltd
>
> 17:16:53 config: loading user config
>
> 17:16:53 bouncer: initializing polkit
>
> 17:16:53 udev: initializing udev
>
> 17:16:53 store: loading domains
>
> 17:16:53 store: loading devices
>
> 17:16:53 power: state located at: /run/boltd/power
>
> 17:16:53 power: force power support: yes
>
> 17:16:53 power: setting force_power to ON
>
> 17:16:53 power: state changed: supported/on
>
> 17:16:53 power: guard '1' for 'boltd' active
>
> 17:16:58 udev: found 0 domain
>
> 17:16:58 manager: acquired power guard '1'
>
> 17:16:58 udev: enumerating devices
>
> 17:16:58 power: guard '1' for 'boltd' deactivated
>
> 17:16:58 power: shutdown scheduled (T-20.00s)
>
> 17:16:58 power: state changed: supported/wait

[console_view_Ubuntu19.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV0go.png)  [console_view_Fedora31_LiveUSB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q00Fv.png)

```
dmesg | grep thunderbolt                                                                                                                                             
[    1.331789] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   28.269285] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: failed to read root switch config space, giving up
[   28.269603] thunderbolt: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -110
```

try also auto-authorize:

> cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-removable.rules
>   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="thunderbolt", ATTR{authorized}=="0", ATTR{authorized}="1"

So basically my potencial Question is:  How to set bolt3 security to user and allow it ?

live USB Fedora31, do work, But I am looking for documentation or things to try and learn.

Comment: wow , it was a kernel thing .. works on older 5.0.0-32-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 02:06:48 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux